# C# winforms 'Control' does not contain a definition for 'BorderStyle'

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a winforms app using VS 2022 and getting the above error.
Checking MSDN there is no Control property called `BorderStyle`.  Instead `BorderStyle` documentation is found under Windows Desktop 6.

This is my code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Library
{
    public class Styles : Form
    {
        public static void Label_as_Button_Enable(Control ctrlName)
        {
            ctrlName.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(214, 206, 165);
            ctrlName.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
            ctrlName.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            ctrlName.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
            ctrlName.Enabled = true;
            ctrlName.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        }
```

All of the other properties are compiling.  Looking in the Designer file I find "controlName".BorderStyle = etc so I was surprised when this didn't work.  What should I be using instead of `Control`?
Thank you.

Comment: The `Control` class is the base class for all controls (and for `Form`).  Not everything has a Border style.  If you want to change border style for buttons, you can do something like `if (ctrlName is Button btn) { /* same code, but using btn, not ctrlName */ }`

Comment: When in doubt, check the docs: [Control Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control).

Comment: fyi @Flydog57 - `Button` does not have a `BorderStyle` property. The OP is creating a method to make a `Label` look like a button, or at least that's what the method name implies.

Comment: Oh, that jumble of letters in various cases (`LBLasBTN`) is `LabelAsButton`.  I just recognized the `BTN` part (and my eyes did notice `Las`)

Comment: My apologies; I thought my introductory statements made it clear that before posting a question I consulted the relevant MSDN docs.  I'll try to be more explicit in the future.  Your link takes me to one of the pages I consulted and even re-reading it in light of the solutions you provide below there's no way I'd have arrived at those solutions based on the material presented in the documentation. (And yes, I'm making a label look/behave like a button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A WinForm `Control` is just a common base class for all WinForm controls: [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control). Not all WinForm controls have a border/border style.

There are a couple of options if you want to set the border style with a generic method.

### Reflection

Using reflection is basically a catch-all here and will only set the border style if a border style property exists:

```cs
public static void LBLasBTN_Enable( Control ctrl )
{
    ctrl.BackColor = Color.FromArgb( 214, 206, 165 );
    ctrl.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb( 0, 0, 0 );
    ctrl.Font = new Font( "Segoe UI", 8, FontStyle.Bold );
    ctrl.Enabled = true;
    ctrl.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

    PropertyInfo pi = ctrl.GetType().GetProperty( "BorderStyle", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance );
    if( pi != null )
    {
        pi.SetValue( ctrl, BorderStyle.FixedSingle );
    }
}
```

### Casting

Alternatively, the control can be cast into whatever type you expect to have a border style:

```cs
public static void LBLasBTN_Enable( Control ctrl )
{
    ctrl.BackColor = Color.FromArgb( 214, 206, 165 );
    ctrl.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb( 0, 0, 0 );
    ctrl.Font = new Font( "Segoe UI", 8, FontStyle.Bold );
    ctrl.Enabled = true;
    ctrl.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

    if( ctrl is Label lbl )
    {
        lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }

    // add other types as needed...
}
```

Personally I'm a bit lazy and would just go the reflection route. However, if you want to be fully explicit, then go the casting route.

Comment: I've not yet delved into Reflection (tho I may be approaching that stage) but the Casting approach is working perfectly.  Thanx for your time & expertise.